# Не работающая кнопка закрытия модального окна

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, всплывающее-окно

Есть кнопка закрытия окна

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть код, всплывающего окна

```js
$(function() {

    $('.close-over, .close-undermodal').on('click', function (e) {
        // $('#comebacker').fadeOut(300); // 300 скорость исчезновения | disappear speed
        // console.log(e);
        let comebackerwindow=document.getElementById('comebacker');
        comebackerwindow.style.display='none';    
        // $('#comebacker').style.display='none';
        $('body').removeClass('comebackerhidden');
    });


    var comebacker = true;

    /*
    $(window).mouseout(function(e){
        if(e.pageY - $(window).scrollTop() < 1 && comebacker == true){
            $('#comebacker').fadeIn(300); 
            $('body').addClass('comebackerhidden');
            comebacker = false;
        }
    });
    */

    $(window).on('popstate',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(comebacker==true) {
            $('#comebacker').fadeIn(300);
            $('body').addClass('comebackerhidden');
            comebacker = false;
        }
    });

    $(window).on('beforeunload',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(comebacker==true) {
            $('#comebacker').fadeIn(300);
            $('body').addClass('comebackerhidden');
            comebacker = false;
        }
    });

    try {
        setTimeout(
            function show_comebacker() {
                $('#comebacker').fadeIn(300); // 300 скорость появления | appear speed 
                $('body').addClass('comebackerhidden');
            }, 3000 //Время появления в милисекундах | Appear time in milliseconds
        )
    }
    catch (e) {}
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700&subset=cyrillic-ext,latin-ext);

/* modal */
#comebacker {
    background: url(img/bgexit.png);
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0; 
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
    overflow: auto;
/*  display: none;*/
}   

#comebacker .close-undermodal {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#comebacker .close-over {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4oWi.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#comebacker .close-over:hover {
    background-position: 0 bottom;
} 

#comebacker .over-window {
    background: url(img/product.png) no-repeat 40px center #fff;
    cursor: default;
    left: 0;
    right: 0; 
    top: 10%;
    margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 60px 20px 60px 20px;
    width: 560px;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'PT Sans',arial,sans-serif !important;
} 

#comebacker .title-comebacker {
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 0 30px 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 50%;
}

#comebacker .title-oui div{
    font-size: 20px;
}

#comebacker .form {
    margin: 0 0 0 50%;
}

#comebacker .form form {
    margin: 0 !important;
}

#comebacker .form input[type="text"] {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #a5a5a5;
    outline: none;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'PT Sans',arial,sans-serif;
    width: 250px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 20px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

#comebacker .form input[type="text"]:focus {
    border: 1px solid #054155;
}

#comebacker .form input[type="submit"] {
    background: #054155;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    outline: none;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'PT Sans',arial,sans-serif;
    width: 250px; 
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    border: 0px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#comebacker .form input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: #10a9dc;
}

.comebackerhidden {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Comebacker</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="comebacker/css.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script
    <script type="text/javascript" src="comebacker/script.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script src="myPopupWindow.js"></script>-->
</head>
<body>
TestContent
<a href="www.google.ru">Google</a>
<div id="comebacker">
    <div class="close-undermodal"></div>
    <div class="over-window">
        <div class="close-over"></div>
        <div class="title-comebacker">
            <div>Order today!</div>
            Only: 15 $.
            <div>50% discount</div>
        </div>
        <div class="form">
            <form method="post" action="">
                <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Name" />
                <input type="text" name="phone" value="" placeholder="Phone" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Order" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Не срабатывает кнопка закрытия (крестик) окна `#comebacker`. Подскажите, как добиться функционирования кнопки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У *Jquery* объекта нет свойств и методов объектов из простого *JS*, поэтому у него просто не может быть свойства `.style`

Можно в данном случае просто сделать вот так:

```
$('#comebacker').hide();
```

Если нужен именно `.style`, тогда надо испльзовать либо `document.querySelector`, либо `document.getElementById`

Comment: я обновил вопрос

Comment: @vladwebsearch так и что? там вё работает вполне

Comment: у вас все работает?

Comment: Ну если я пишу, что работает....Откройте сниппет у себя же в вопросе и посмотрите

Comment: а у меня не работает. См. вопрос.

Comment: @vladwebsearch все работает корректно. То что Вы прикрепили в тексте как ошибку, это вообще-то `console.log(e)` внутри `$('.close-over, .close-undermodal').on('click', function() {});`

Comment: @Simon окно не закрывается. Оно ведь должно исчезнуть после щелчка на кнопке?

Comment: @vladwebsearch У меня все прекрасно исчезает. И уберите тот текстовый файл, это просто консоль лог ивента клика.

Comment: @vladwebsearch `console.log(e)` уберите, из-за него браузер виснет, особенно если сделать несколько щелчков.

Comment: @vladwebsearch если убрать console log, который убивает всю работу напрочь, то можно будет увидеть что всё работает